# C# Generic Excel Reader and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have multiple projects where I read an excel file and the contents are put in to the database. How do I make this generic? Instead of having AddContentsToDatabase reference specific entity and specific type, may I specify the entity name and object type as strings in the app.config?

I looked up examples with the repository pattern, but couldn't reference dbContext correctly.

The parts where the code is different are:

```
private void AddContentsToDatabase()
{
   using(var db = new xEntities())
   {
     foreach (var k in MyObjectDictionary.Keys)
      {
       MyObject thisO = new MyObject();
       db.Add(thisO);
      }

     db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

Comment: I fear EF is not the best tool for the job because if you want to map tabular data (spreadsheet) to tabular data (relationnal schema) adding EF in the middle might be a pure waste of time (and money for your company ;)) and will probably lead to complex code and overengineering. So you'd better use some standard ADO.Net `DataSet`/`DataTable` stuff...

Comment: You're right. Another approach may be do dependency injection for the specific spreadsheet reader.

Comment: DI could help for the global architecture but won't help for the data processing. And in most of the projects that use DI this is pure overengineering again. Concerning your primary issue could you tell us more about the kind of data you import and how you intend to use them?

Comment: I created a solution to my problem below. I simplify it by not referencing logging or emailing the group on success or failure. My excel reader projects have the requirement of logging, and emailing. Instead of creating multiple project to call the same libraries, using dependency injection I created the reader class and reference the class name in app.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In App.config

```
<add key="DataParserName" value="XReader" />
```

In Program.cs

```
static void Main()
{            
  var dependency = GetCorrectDataParser();
  dependency.Run()
}

    private static IDataParser GetCorrectDataParser()
     {

        try
          {
           var classToCreate = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataParserName"];
           var type = Type.GetType(classToCreate);
            if (type == null) return null;

           var dependency = (IDataParser) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            return dependency;
           }
       catch (Exception ex)
       { throw ex;}
           return null;
      }
```

In XReader class have the appropriate parsing of file and putting the information into the database.

Change XReader to YReader in App.config, etc when the there's another different type of Excel file to parse. Create the class for YReader.